# String Manipulation in java 1.6

Tags: java, java-6

String can be like below. Using java1.6

```
String example = "<number>;<name-value>;<name-value>";

String abc = "+17005554141;qwq=1234;ddd=ewew;otg=383";
String abc = "+17005554141;qwq=123454";
String abc = "+17005554141";
```

I want to remove `qwq=1234` if present from String. `qwq` is fixed and its value can `VARY` like for ex 1234 or 12345 etc

expected result :

```
String abc = "+17005554141;ddd=ewew;otg=383";
String abc = "+17005554141"; \\removed ;qwq=123454
String abc = "+17005554141";
```

I tried through

```
abc = abc.replaceAll(";qwq=.*;", "");
```

but not working.

Comment: "but not working" ... what do you mean? what error do you get, or what result do you get? it's quite clear the code you've posted above isn't the code you run, so what exactly is the code you run, and what result do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? And when you use two semicolon to match your String, then you need to add at lease one semicolon again. Or, to avoid issues when "qwq" is the last element, don't use the semicolon at all.

Comment: Getting this result : +17005554141otg=383

Comment: Now i tried this : abc = abc.replaceAll(";isub=.;*", "");  Looks like its working

Comment: That's exactly something that should be fixed by what @Tom suggested. Replace the matches by `";"` not an empty string as you are matching both semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this `qwq=\d*\;?` and it works. It matches for 0 or more decimals after `qwq=`. It also has an optional parameter `;` since your example seems to include that this is not always appended after the number.

I know the question is not about javascript, but here's an example where you can see the regex working:

```js
const regex = /qwq=\d*\;?/g;
var items = ["+17005554141;qwq=123454",
            "+17005554141",
            "+17005554141;qwq=1234;ddd=ewew;otg=383"];

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log("Item before replace: " + items[i]);
  console.log("Item after replace: " + items[i].replace(regex, "") + "\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for removing that kind of string like this. Use this code,

```
String example = "+17005554141;qwq=1234;ddd=ewew;otg=383";
System.out.println("Before: " + example);
System.out.println("After: " + example.replaceAll("qwq=\\d+;?", ""));
```

This gives following output,

```
Before: +17005554141;qwq=1234;ddd=ewew;otg=383
After: +17005554141;ddd=ewew;otg=383
```

Comment: Yes, it will fail.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that sample input... Just a little modification was needed. Edited my regex and now it will work

Answer (score 1):

`.*` applies to multi-characters, **not limited to digits**. Use something that applies only to bunch of digits

```
abc.replaceAll(";qwq=\\d+", "")
                      ^^
                      Any Number
```

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
abc = abc.replaceAll("qwq=[0-9]*;", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about too much convenience, you can achieve this by just plain simple String operations (`indexOf`, `replace` and `substring`). This is maybe the most legacy way to do this:

```
private static String replaceQWQ(String target)
{
    if (target.indexOf("qwq=") != -1) {
        if (target.indexOf(';', target.indexOf("qwq=")) != -1) {
            String replace =
                target.substring(target.indexOf("qwq="), target.indexOf(';', target.indexOf("qwq=")) + 1);
            target = target.replace(replace, "");
        } else {
            target = target.substring(0, target.indexOf("qwq=") - 1);
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Small test:

```
String abc = "+17005554141;qwq=1234;ddd=ewew;otg=383";
String def = "+17005554141;qwq=1234";

System.out.println(replaceQWQ(abc));
System.out.println(replaceQWQ(def));
```

outputs:

```
+17005554141;ddd=ewew;otg=383
+17005554141
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
abc.replaceAll(";qwq=[^;]*;", ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to use groups in replaceAll method.

Here is an example:

```
abc.replaceAll("(.*;)(qwq=\\d*;)(.*)", "$1$3");
```

More about groups you can find on: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html